# Compute $\mathbb{E}[\cos(aX)]$ if $X$ has a standard normal distribution, and $a$ is a scalar

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

If $X$ has a standard normal distribution, what is the expected value $\mathbb{E}\left[\cos(aX)\right]$, with $a$ being a scalar?

I have tried to compute it as

$\mathbb{E}[\cos(aX)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(ax)\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dx $

but I cannot figure out how to perform this integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Ee^{iaX}=e^{-a^{2}/2}$.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Just take real part to get $E\cos (aX)=e^{-a^{2}/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

*HINT:* consider $$J(a) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos(ax) \phi(x)dx$$

Note that:
$$
J'(a) = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \sin(ax) x \phi(x)dx = - \sin(ax) \dfrac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Big|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} + \int_{\mathbb{R}} a\cos(ax) \phi(x) dx
$$